# Hello to everyone, what do you recommend to put after the empty for loop(I don't know what to put there)?

Tags: python, class, for-loop

**This is  a code for calculating distance between two coordinates using distance formula.**

```
import math
class Line():
    
    def __init__(self,coor1,coor2):
        self.coor1=coor1
        self.coor2=coor2
    def fun(self):
        self.coor1=[x_one,y_one]
        self.coor2=[x_two,y_two]
        for e in [self.coor1,self.coor2]:
            **what to put in??!!**
        u=((self.coor1[0]-self.coor2[0])**2+(self.coor1[1]-self.coor2[1])**2)
        p=math.sqrt(u)
        print(f'the answer is{p}')
```

Comment: `pass`? I don't see why you need that loop in the first place. The assignments to `self.coor1` and `self.coor2` don't seem necessary (even if `x_one` et al) had been defined; presumably they were initialized correctly when you instantiate `Line`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `fun()` method have to **read** `self.coor1`, `self.coor2`, and not set them again.
   (They were set in the `__init__()` method already.)
2. The calculation is straightforward enough — no need to use a loop:

```
import math


class Line():
    def __init__(self, coor1, coor2):
        self.coor1 = coor1
        self.coor2 = coor2

    def fun(self):
        x_1, y_1 = self.coor1
        x_2, y_2 = self.coor2
        u = (x_2 - x_1) ** 2 + (y_2 - y_1) ** 2
        return math.sqrt(u)
    

### Using this Line class

point1 = (1, 4)
point2 = (5, 7)

line = Line(point1, point2)
p = line.fun()

print(f'The distance is {p}.')
```

---

*The output:*

> The distance is 5.0.

Comment: thank you! you helped me so much

Comment: i need help in c language about for loop(I am beginner) if you want to help me watch my profile and see my last question